# What is a good resource for flavor contributions of different ingredients?

Tags: beer, hops, malt

For those of us who are still brewing from kits and recipes and want to branch out and try building our own flavors, what resources are there that describe the various flavors contributed by particular specialty malts and strains of hops?

For example, how would the flavor profile of an Irish Red change if I replaced the Kent Golding Hops with, say, Saaz or Cascade hops?  Or if I were to replace some of the Cara Munich malt with a Crystal malt?

Comment: Both answers are quite useful.  Wish I could accept more than one :)

Answer (score 4):

I always thought this was a helpful chart for hops, don't know the original source though.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkfmg.jpg

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty good chart for malts: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Malts_Chart

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: Av very useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

It's covered in the book "Experimental Homebrewing"

Comment: Nice self-plug there, Denny ;) In all honesty though, it's a great book!